# Need regular expression to allow maximum of 3 special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression which fulfills below requirements.

1. should accept alphanumeric with the length in between 0 to 50 characters
2. should accept all special characters except ','
3. should accept minimum of 0 and maximum of 3 special characters.

Tried this, but its not working as expected.

```
^[a-z\s]{0,50}[.\-']*[a-z\s]{0,50}[.\-']*$
```

Please let me know, if some one gets this right.

Comment: did you want to allow zero special characters? Show your efforts..

Comment: I need the moon on a stick, but if I don't show any effort in getting my moon on a stick, why would I expect anyone else to help me?

Comment: yeah, zero special characters also allowed

Comment: @spender: Added the regular expression which i am trying.

Comment: special character = non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: @Jenny O'Reilly: Yes

Comment: If the 3 non-alphanumeric characters can be scattered among the 50 total characters, I think it is not possible to solve this problem with one regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could either write some monstrous regexp, which would be impossible to read or maintain, or just write code which says what the rules are:

```
function validate(str) {
    var not_too_long          = str.length <= 50,
        has_no_dots           = !/\./.test(str),
        not_too_many_specials = (str.match(/[^\w\s]/g) || []).length <= 3;

    return not_too_long && has_no_dots && not_too_many_specials;
}
```

with appropriate adjustments for your definition of "special characters".

Comment: Edited the answer as, \W also considering the spaces as special characters